# My jquery .fadeOut() isn't working?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a jQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.div').click(function () {
        $(this).fadeOut(100);
    });
});
```

With some HTML:

```
<div class='div'>jhkhjk</div>
```

Though for some reason it isn't working.

Here is the fiddle for it:

http://jsfiddle.net/Cx5HG/

Comment: it does: http://jsfiddle.net/Cx5HG/1/

Comment: You forgot to include the jQuery library in your jsFiddle.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot some sort of ajax file.

Here is a working fiddle

The Jquery is still the same:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.div').click(function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(100);
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Cx5HG/1/